# Is sIFR 3 compatible with the jQuery Cycle Plugin?

Tags: jquery, sifr

I am a newbie and I have been struggling with this for awhile. I am try to create a scrolling div using the jQuery Cycle Plugin with sIFR 3 text within the scrolling div. I can get it to work properly in Firefox and that's about it. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's my link: http://dev.bandspecial.com/test.html

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#slideshow').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollLeft',
    cleartypeNoBg:  true
});
});
```

sIFR:

```
sIFR.replace(rockwell, {
 selector: 'h1',
      css: [ '.sIFR-root { color:#ffffff; }' ,'a { text-decoration: none }' ,'a:link { color: #E31824 }' ,'a:hover { color: #E31824 }' ], wmode: 'transparent'
    });
```

Body Code:

```
<div id="slideshow">
  <div> <img src="http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/images/beach1.jpg" height="200" width="200">
    <h1>St Andrews State Park - Panama City, FL</h1>
    <p>This park is one of the most popular outdoor recreation spots in Florida. </p>
  </div>
  <div> <img src="http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/images/beach2.jpg" height="200" width="200">
    <h1>Located in the Florida panhandle,</h1>
    <p> the 1,260 acre park is situated on a scenic peninsula and is well known for its sugar white sands and brilliant blue water. </p>
  </div>
  <div> <img src="http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/images/beach3.jpg" height="200" width="200">
    <h1>The ocean provides opportunity for endless fun. </h1>
    <p>From boogie boarding to snorkeling to  swimming and boating, there is always something to do.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: I've added the code and the link above.

Answer (score 2):

I adjusted Tom's code a bit. Although his code works for me, it visibly renders the sifr after the (fade) effect. With a before and a display block, the sifr is rendered before the effect for a more desirable result.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#div').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        before: function(){
            $(this).css({ 'display': 'block' })
            sIFR.replace(alberta, {
            selector: '.flash-text',
            wmode: 'transparent'
            });
       }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the `Innerfade` Jquery plugin so the changes may be a little different.

Here is what I did:

Innerfade uses `.hide()` to hide all items in a list. This is the root of the problem.
Solution: instead of having your plugin utilize `.hide()`, use `.addClass("hide")` and define the CSS `position: absolute; left:-10000px`.

Using this method. `.removeClass("hide")` will make your post appear again. In addition to this, if you are using an effect like fade or slide don't forget to `removeClass` there as well.

I hope this makes sense. BTW: I am using SIFR 3

Answer (score 0):

If you divs that are hidden that you are trying to scroll to have a display:none; on page load, sifr will not replace that text.

Answer (score 0):

I used the jquery cycle option 'after' to call the sIFR function once each transition is completed:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#div').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        after: function(){
            sIFR.replace(alberta, {
            selector: '.flash-text',
            wmode: 'transparent'
            });
        }
    });
});
```